# storyboard for UITableViewCell designing

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I've not used storyboard before.

I want to design a custom table view cell, and want to do it with interface builder.

I've created a storyboard and put a viewController (of custom class) and put the custom cell under it.

I also connected the outlets for cell's labels.

However, when I try to access the label, it's always nil.

I am using the following code to instantiate the code, and I suspect that's where I'm failing.

I feel like I should somehow tell I want the viewcontroller from storyboard shouldn't I?

```
 ThreadTempDatasViewController* threadTempDatasViewController = [[ThreadTempDatasViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: threadTempDatasViewController animated: NO];
```

** EDIT **

I now have

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ThreadTempData" bundle:nil];
 ThreadTempDatasViewController *threadTempDatasViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThreadTempDatasViewController"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController: threadTempDatasViewController animated: NO];
```

and I get error

> Storyboard () doesn't contain a view
>   controller with identifier 'ThreadTempDatasViewController'

So How do I inform the storyboard that he has this viewcontroller other than putting the viewcontroller in the storyboard in interfacebuilder?

** EDIT 2 **

answer> You should set Storyboard ID for the viewcontroller in the interfacebuilder.

Now I'm back where I was, the cell's label is nil..

** EDIT 3 **

answer> so you shouldn't have `self.tableView.registerClass(ThreadTempDataTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ThreadTempDataTableViewCell")` when you are using interfacebuilder.

I set `ThreadTempDataTableViewCell` for table view cell's class field in IB and used it like the following.

```
 let cellIdentifier = "ThreadTempDataTableViewCell"
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThreadTempDataTableViewCell
```

Comment: Did you activate your view controller in the storyboard (klick it), and set in the right pane in the identity inspector the storyboard ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see couple of issues. So, I am going to give you a step by step instruction. What I understood is you want to have a View Controller which will hold a Table View and inside that Table View, you want to have a custom TableView Cell.

So, other than trying to instantiate the ViewController incorrectly, I feel there is one more thing. You need to have a TableView to hold your TableView Cell.

So, here are the steps you need to consider:

**Step 1:** Drag a View Controller in your storyboard. In my case, my storyboard's name is "Main".

So, just a heads up on how to load a ViewController using storyboard identifier-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ThreadTempDatasViewController *threadTempDatasViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThreadTempDatasViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: threadTempDatasViewController animated: NO];
```

So, back to adding object to your View Controller-
Now drag and drop a UITableView in the View of your UIViewController. Then drag and drop a UITableViewCell inside your TableView.

Now, select the TableViewCell to expand and drag and drop a UILabel inside your TableViewCell's content view.

The View Hierarchy would look something like this-

[image]

So, you have all the objects you in place now.

**Step 2:** Give your View Controller the ID, "ThreadTempDatasViewController" and assign its class(ThreadTempDatasViewController) from Identity inspector in your storyboard.

[image]

**Step 3:** Select the TableViewCell and set it's ReuseIdentifier which is "ThreadTempDataTableViewCell" in your case that way, you won't have to register the cell identified programatically.

[image]

Also don't forget to assign its custom class which in your case is "ThreadTempDataTableViewCell"

[image]

**Step 4:** 
Select your custom TableViewCell and connect the outlets with the desired UI objects. So, connect the Outlet of your UILabel which has to be declared inside your ThreadTempDataTableViewCell.h class with the label in the storyboard inside your cell.

For example, if the ThreadTempDataTableViewCell.h have an Outlet of UILabel called "threadTempDataLAbel", it will be something like-

```
@interface ThreadTempDataTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *threadTempDataLAbel;

@end
```

Now select the ThreadTempDataTableViewCell in your storyboard and then go to the last icon in your identity inspector, and connect with your outlet.

[image]

After connection, you will see something like-

[image]

For the sake of clarity, you should also have an IBOutlet of your TableView in your ViewController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThreadTempDatasViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

Now, select the ViewController in the storyboard and go to the last tab like before and connect with the tableView's outlet.

[image]

Well, this should be all the set up you need. Now you can jump into your code to populate the table or access the TableViewCell's property(threadTempDataLabel)

I think, the reason, you couldn't access your UILabel is either because you you were trying to set a TableViewCell inside your ViewController rather than your TableView or if you have a TableView, you may have forgot to set the datasource to the view controller. Here is the complete code.

```
#import "ThreadTempDatasViewController.h"
#import "ThreadTempDataTableViewCell.h"

@interface ThreadTempDatasViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThreadTempDatasViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.myTableView.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark- TableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ThreadTempDataTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ThreadTempDataTableViewCell"];
    cell.threadTempDataLAbel.text  = @"test";
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! it would be complete tutorial if you added my 2 edits. 1 for how I load the viewcontroller programmatically, and 2 for not registering class.

Comment: Thanks, I added the edit of how to load a View Controller with the help of storyboard. About registering the cell's class, you won't have to do it, if you specify the Cell's identifier property in your storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

When you want use to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` , make sure you have set the right identifier in Interface Builder. You can find it on a ViewController's Identity inspector in Interface Builder.

I guess you've declared the label in your Cell's class and try to access it. If you did that, make sure you've set the cell's class to your class and link up the properties outlet correctly in Interface Builder.

Comment: please let me know the code how you get the cell and your IB config of the cell first.